# RazorEngine within VS single file generator is too slow

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, razorengine, single-file-generator

I'm developing a Visual Studio custom tool(single file generator) that generates a .vue file for each selected razor page(*.cshtml), the project is based on the Microsoft's single file generator sample project [https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/Single_File_Generator], I'm using [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) to parse razor template, everything works as expected except that the RazorEngine took a lot of time (more than 20 seconds) to compile the razor template file and caused VS to hang without response, I looked into the task manager and noticed that there's a Visual C# command line compiler that took a high CPU usage while this custom tool is running, my code is as follows:

```
protected override byte[] GenerateCode(string inputFileContent)
        {
            try
            {
                var result=Engine.Razor.RunCompile(inputFileContent,DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());
                return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                this.GeneratorError(4, e.ToString(), 1, 1);
                //Returning null signifies that generation has failed
                return null;
            }
        }
```

The problem is caused by this line of code:

```
Engine.Razor.RunCompile(inputFileContent,DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());
```

But when I run it within a console application, it only takes a few milliseconds to complete, I googled for a whole day and can't solve this problem, please help me! Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone have any idea what caused this problem? thank!

Answer (score 0):

Look closely what you are passing as a template key:

```
DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()
```

Basically, you create a new cache entry every time you run `RunCompile()`. What you need to do is to reuse the key, if the template already compiled.

You can handle that in a following way:

Generate a hash sum for a template:

```
using MD5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5;
...
public static class HashGenerator
{
    public static string GenerateCheckSumHash(string input)
    {
        using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
        {
            byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
            byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(hashBytes[i].ToString("X2"));
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Use a hash sum as a template key:

```
var result = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(inputFileContent,
    HashGenerator.GenerateCheckSumHash(inputFileContent));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! The template key is not a problem, the hash sum method I've already used before and the result is the same. The template is the file that user editing in the Visual Studio IDE, so it's not necessary to be cached. This slow compilation problem I've solved by creating a new AppDomain with IsolatedRazorEngineService, but  referenced  assemblies failed to load into this new appdomain and referenced codes can not be compiled. I've given up creating this VS extension and compile razor files within project instead. thanks again!

Comment: @Webdiyer can you share me how to handle with appDomain isolatedRazor service for caching template to quick load?  thank you